# iOS | Difference between approach of presenting new ViewController object and Using Segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I have a big confusion on new screen presentation architecture in iOS. I can present a screen by below two approaches.

1.By Making object of view controller

```
UIStoryboard* sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"SecondStoryboard" bundle:nil];
MyViewController* myVC = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyViewController"];

// Configure the view controller.

// Display the view controller
[self presentViewController:myVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

2.By making segue in the story board

I can make segue from story board to achieve the same

NOTE :  I am considering the case where both ViewControllers are on same storyboard. If both ViewControllers are on different storyboard than obviously we can't use segue

Query :
I an confused what difference is there in above two approaches. When should I use then for a good architecture. Is there any difference on memory consumption. Apple should have introduced segue for a specific purpose.
Thanks in advance for sharing your valuable knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use of segues wherever possible:

- they add greatly to the understanding of the app's navigational structure
- any memory overhead will be negligible compared to the memory used to instantiate your new view controller
- you CAN segue to view controllers in other storyboards using storyboard references (http://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/8.0/#/dev66c5f17da)